# Are those regular expressions are correct?

Tags: formal-languages, regular-expressions

Let Σ = {a, b}. Construct a regular expression defining each of the following languages over Σ.

(a) The language of all words that do not begin with ba

```
Answer: (a + b + ab + aa) a* b*
```

(b) The language of all words in which the total number of b’s is divisible by 3 nomatter how they are distributed, such as bbabbaabab

```
Answer: (a* ba* ba* ba*)*
```

Comment: what do you mean by that (expression)* notation? any number of repetitions of (expression)?

Comment: then for your first case you need  (a* b*)* instead of a* b* at the end, the second should be fine. otherwise you only have a sequence of a, then a sequence of b, not an arbitrary sequence of a's and b's.AND again for the first case i think (a + bb) instead of that other sum should be enough (but your sum is not wrong, just longer)

Comment: @Max You're right on all counts; why not make that an answer?

Comment: That's right Max. It should be an accepted answer

Comment: For (b), what about the string `aaaaaaaaaaa` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the **first problem**, anything that starts with an `a`, or just `b`, or anything that starts with a `b` then not an `a`:

`a(a + b)* + b + bb(a + b)*`

---

In a systematic way:

If we expand all possible strings, making the first two symbols explicit, we have

```
a + b + aa(a + b)* + ab(a + b)* + ba(a + b)* + bb(a + b)*
```

From these, we discard those beginning with `ba`, leaving

```
a + b + aa(a + b)* + ab(a + b)* + bb(a + b)*
```

---

Optionally we can compress the three terms beginning in `a` by

```
a + aa(a + b)* + ab(a + b)* = a + a(a + b)(a + b)* = a(a + b)*
```

and a final grouping is possible

```
a(a + b)* + b + bb(a + b)* = (a + bb)(a + b)* + b
```

---

The solution in the OP isn't valid as it does allow `ba` (choice `b` in the parenthesis, then `a*` once).

---

For the **second problem**, let us consider all strings with multiples of three `b`'s

```
(bbb)*
```

and let us insert abritrary strings of `a` wherever possible: we get

```
a* (a* b a* b a* b a*)* a*
```

---

This solution is valid. Anyway, it leaves multiples possibilities for the decomposition of the initial and final strings of `a`, because of sequences `a*a*`. These can be avoided by the mergings `a*a* = a*`, which give the unambiguous

```
a* (b a* b a* b a*)*
```

---

The solution in the OP isn't valid as is does not represent the strings without any `b`, though they should be accepted.